# Increase distance between title and plot in matplolib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, title, margins

I have a simple plot in matplotlib and I would like to increase the distance between the title and the plot (without using `suptitle` because it does not work on the version I use on a server). How to do that ?

Comment: Isn't it possible to simply put some blank line(s) after the title? You could even play with the `linespacing` kwarg of `text`.

Comment: I found just adding \n after the string left the space I needed

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a clean way to set this directly (but might be worth a feature request to add that), however the title is just a `text` artist, so you can reach in and change it.

```
#ax = plt.gca()
ttl = ax.title
ttl.set_position([.5, 1.05])
#plt.draw()
```

should do the trick.  Tune the `1.05` to your liking.

Answer (score 157):

With `matplotlib 2.2+`, you can use the keyword argument `pad`:

```
ax.set_title('Title', pad=20)
```

Adjust `pad` until you're happy with the axis title position. The advantage of this method over using `rcParams` is that it only changes this one axis title.

Comment: You can do `ax.xaxis.labelpad=10.0` as well as `yaxis` and `zaxis`

Comment: @TedoVrbanec For axis labels, you can do `ax.set_xlabel('label', labelpad=20)`. Adjust the `labelpad` parameter until you're happy.

Answer (score 47):

You can just pass `y` parameter into `plt.suptitle` method:

```
plt.suptitle('Amazing Stats', size=16, y=1.12);
```

Comment: Good! In matplotlib `v2.0.0` it works also for `plt.title()`.

Answer (score 27):

Using `rcParams`:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['axes.titlepad'] = 20
```

where `20` is the padding between the plot and the title.

From https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

Comment: the documentation in the link only lists 'axes.titlepad'. possibly a typo?

Comment: @keisuke Correct. Thank you for spotting this. I have updated the answer.

Comment: In Python3 *"KeyError: 'axes.titlepad is not a valid rc parameter"*.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco are you using an up-to-date version of matplotlib?

Answer (score 13):

Another possibility is to reduce the relative size of the plot with respect to the whole figure window. In that way the distance between title and plot increases.

Before showing the plot, i.e. before `plt.show()`, write following command:

```
#The standard value of 'top' is 0.9,
#tune a lower value, e.g., 0.8
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)
```

This method has the advantage over @CanCeylan method that the title never goes out of the figure window; because if the title is large enough, then moving it upwards through the parameter `y` in `suptitle` might move the title outside the figure. (as it happened to me ;))

Comment: i had an older version of matplotlib ... so i wasn't able to use the 'axes.titlepad' solutions. so yours worked great! thanks a million.