# Title using matplotlib and pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Any idea why my script below places the title so far from the graphs/subplots? Is it possible to specify the font size of the title?

```
df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=',', 
                             index_col=0, 
                             parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True, 
                             names=['Date','1','2','3','4', '5'])

        df.plot(subplots=True, marker='.',markersize=8, title ="Graph", fontsize = 10, color=['r','b','b','b', 'b'], figsize=(8, 18))


        plt.savefig('capture.png')
```

Thanks a ton!

Comment: have you had a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419670/increase-distance-between-title-and-plot-in-matplolib)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to use `matplotlib` to edit the font size, as pandas does not allow passing for font sizes or similar, unfortunately (afaik).

try this:

```
ax = df.plot()
ax.set_title('Graph', fontsize=20)  # or size, alternatively
```

Essentially, `pandas.DataFrame.plot()` returns a matplotlib `axis` object, on which you then can call any methods associated with it.

For more, check out [the matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html).